# Windows 10 Can't access samba share

Tags: 16.04, samba

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1. I have Samba 4.
Windows writes access denied. I can reach the shared folder, but I can't access. My `smb.conf` file:

```
[megosztas]
path = /home/attila/Asztal/megosztas
available = yes
valid users = fel1
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
```

Comment: What are the permissions of that folder? Run `ls -ld /home/attila/Asztal/megosztas` to find out.

Comment: drwxrwxrwx 2 attila attila 4096 nov    6 18:27 /home/attila/Asztal/megosztas                This is the output

Comment: I tried smbclient to login, but that also failed. The output: Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Windows 6.1] Server=[Samba 4.3.11-Ubuntu]
tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: Does the user fel1 exist on Ubuntu?

Comment: I solved the problem. I just added the smbpasswd before I added the user with adduser. I just used smbpasswd -a user again. :)

Comment: @icebolt, you should enter your solution as an answer, and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I just added the smbpasswd before I added the user with adduser. I just used smbpasswd -a user again

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)